# When I run Visual Studio debug mode, the Unreal Editor does not fully open

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine5, unreal

I am a student studying game programming in Korea. **Please understand that I am not good at English.**

**I'm studying Unreal Engine for the first time.**

To study debug mode, Turned off Unreal Editor, mark breakpoints in **Visual Studio**, and ran debug mode.

That way, the Unreal Editor opens, and I understand that running the editor game will cause a breakpoint.

**However, the Unreal Editor runs only up to 75%, so the editor does not open completely, and then it stops at the breakpoint.**

Here's what I tried.

- Attemped to change the **solution** **configuration** to **`development editor`** or **`debug game editor`**
- Of course, the **solution platform** is **`win64`**.
- I have successfully installed **`the editor symbol for debugging`** in the Engine Options in Launcher.
- The **version** of the Unreal engine is **`5.1.1`**.

To show you the visual data, I'll attach a video link.

https://youtu.be/MUWEq2hAkwI

**It's my first time posting it, so it might be sloppy. Thank you.**

Comment: I solved it!! It was because I put a breakpoint on the constructor. It was a stupid mistake....

Answer (score 1):

---

Remember this.

1. You're doing well.
2. Your language skill is good enough.

---

Build configurations in Visual studio for Unreal Engine are like below.

> - DebugGame / DebugGame Editor
>
>   DebugGame mode means for full debugging symbols.
>
>   If your ar a programmer, you will be used to this mode.
>
>   You can use the full IDE debugger functions in this mode.

> - Development / Development Editor
>
>   Development mode is useful for the non-programmer developers.
>
>   In Development mode, it is slightely faster than debug mode.
>
>   In programmer's sight, debugging symbols are limited(maybe optimised
>   out).
>
>   But your non programming co-workers can execute and work with the
>   your project editor without installing Visual Studio.

> - Shipping
>
>   Shipping mode does not has Editor configuration; It means really
>   packaging.
>
>   This build option is used for the end-build stage.
>
>   Generally used from CI/CD with build script or 'executed editor'
>   operation.

In some reason, DebugGame / Development configuration cannot be executed for the first time.

You should build a package for the project(might be in the unreal project editor)

After the packaging is completed, you can execute under DebugGame / Development mode in the IDE.

Good luck and have a good days.